# How to get the required top elements from array using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, duplicates

I need help in javascript Array Sorting

I have a sorted Array like below:

```
mainArray : [25 20 20 20 18 17 17 15 12 12 10 5 5 ]
```

**mainArray** may or may not contains duplicate value.

**A.Taking the the duplicate case**

Now, based on user input I need to return the **finalArray** with condition below.

1. if user say get top 3 elements then program should return ,

   **finalArray : [25 20 20 20 18]**  or
2. if user say get top 5 then,

   **finalArray : [25 20 20 20 18 17 17 15]**

**B.Taking the the non duplicate case**

```
 mainArray : [25 20 18 17 15 12 10 5  ]
```

Now ,

1. if user say get top 3 elements then program should return ,

   **finalArray : [25 20 18]**  or
2. if user say get top 5 then,

   **finalArray : [25 20 18 17 15]**

Here's the code I've tried:

```
filterLength = 3;//top 3
var finalTarget = [];
for (var i = 0; i < filterLength; i++) {
    if (typeof targetArray[i + 1] !== 'undefined') {
        if (targetArray[i] == targetArray[i + 1]) {
            filterLength++;
        }
    }
    finalTarget.push(targetArray[i]);
}
if (finalTarget.length > targetArray.length) {
    finalTarget.splice(targetArray.length, finalTarget.length - targetArray.length)
}
console.log(finalTarget);
```

any help wold be appreciable.thanks.

Comment: Even my client cannot give requirement like this..! :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I frame the question properly so that one can understood my need.anyways nice comment... :)

Answer (score 0):

it's my code:

```
function sortNumber(a,b)
{
    return a - b
}

function unique(arr) {
  var ret = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var item = arr[i];
    if (ret.indexOf(item) === -1) {
      ret.push(item);
    }
  }

  return ret;
}

function dSort(arr, t, u) {
    if(t > arr.length) {
        t = arr.length;
    }
    if (u) {
        arr = unique(arr);
    }
    arr.sort(sortNumber)

    return arr.slice(0, t);
}


var arr = [1, 55, 12,9, 41, 55, 1, 2, 5, 5];


console.log(dSort(arr, 5, true))
//1,2,5,9,12

console.log(dSort(arr, 5, false))
//1,1,2,5,5
```